# Как задать условие на smarty если нет характеристики 1, 2, 3, 4, то показывается надпись Нет?

Tags: php, smarty

Как сделать так, чтобы показывалась надпись «Нет», если к примеру нет $feature.id_feature == '11', 12, 13, 14?

Comment: что именно вы хотите проверить? что id_feature не принимает значения 11,12,... ? что значит "нет характеристики 1,2.3.4"

Comment: @teran я хочу, чтобы, Если все (например id_feature == 1 && id_feature == 2 и т.д.) id_feature с данными номерами отсутствуют все вместе, то только тогда выводится какая-то информация (в данном случае просто текст «Нет», это может быть что-угодно). Так понятно?

Comment: где они все вместе отсутствуют? у вас есть какой то массив объектов? и надо проверить, что среди них нет указанных ID ?

Comment: @teran да, именно так.

Comment: обновил ответ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задача не совсем для слоя представления, а скорее относится к ответственности контроллера.
тем не менее, для начала вам нужно извлечь существующие ID из вашего массива. И в случае если это массив массивов (или у вас пхп7), то проблемы вообще нет никакой

```
 $ids = array_column($data, 'id_feature');
```

в случае, когда это массив объектов, а у вас пхп 5.х, будет несколько сложнее.

```
 $ids = array_map(function($v){ return $v->id_feature; }, $data);
```

Если первый вариант легко переносится в смарти в виде:

```
{$ids = $data|array_column:'id_feature'}
```

то со вторым так не сделаешь.

Далее, вам нужно определить все ли ваши искомые ключи находятся (отсутствуют) в массиве. В этом поможет `array_intersect()`.

> Функция `array_intersect()` возвращает массив, содержащий все значения массива array1, которые содержатся во всех аргументах.

В общем говоря, вам нужно пересечь искомые значения с исходными. Если длина результата будет 0, значит искомых значений в массиве нет.

```
$x = array_intersect([11,12,13], $ids);
```

Опять же переписывая в смарти:

```
{$x = [11,12,13]|array_intersect:$ids}
```

Поскольку пустой массив вычисляется как `false` значение, то далее вы можете проверить

```
{if !$x}
     нет
{/if}
```

В общем итоге получается что-то вроде:

```
{$ids = $data|array_column:'id_feature'}
{$needle = [11,12,13]}
{$exists = $needle|array_intersect:$ids}
{if !$exists}
     нет
{/if}
```